# Angular App to AppGyver- Port to Mobile Solution

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, steroids, appgyver

I'm beginner to appgyver steroids.

I have angular project. Now I need to make iOS application using [AppGyver](http://www.appgyver.com/).

Instead of modify root view and point it to my angular app url (http://www.yourapp.com) can I add my angular app source / angular project build  to AppGyver project make it iOS application.

Appreciate your comments
Gayan

Answer (score 0):

You can run `steroids create yourApp`. This will walk you through the generation of a multi page or single page application. You can then move the structure of your angular application into the /app folder. Check out the example that the `steroids create` method generates and see the structure there.

You may notice some differences at first. It may take some testing to see what is failing if anything once you port things over. If you used `$rootScope` for anything it is not as reliable in my experience in an iOS or Android application. There are other methods for passing data between views and broadcasting (publish/subscribe) to other controllers.

You will want to use the iOS simulator or http://localhost:4567/app/moduleName/oneOfYourViewsYouAreTesting.html in your favorite browser while `steroids connect` is running to debug.

The version of Angular that is coming with this now is AngularJS v1.3.15 installed via `bower`. You may want to verify things are compatible with your current Angular version.

Ionic is used and Supersonic so you may see conflict with existing CSS or even javascript depending on what you've implemented.

There will be some tricks to learn about preloading views in the `structure.coffee` file and load times / `rootView` / `initialView`. There is lots of support if you come across any issues.

This [forum](https://forums.appgyver.com/#!/) has been really helpful in figuring out any issues I've come across. The Appgyver team is usually pretty responsive to questions directly as well.

They are updating the platform in a few days, and they say big changes are coming. They are hiring a lot of developers right now to take care of [GitHub](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids) issues as well as build out the rest of their incomplete components.

Comment: hi @area28 : once I created new steroids project, I cannt see /app folder.
According to my structure its bower_components,config,dist,logs,node_modules and www Folder.

Comment: When did you install Steroids? What version are you on? Type `steroids -v` in the console. I am on v4.1.0.

Comment: my version is v4.1.1, I installed it recently

Comment: Single page or multi page?

Comment: I selected Single page. But my angular application is pretty much complex.

Comment: Ok that is why the structure is different than I expected. Try creating a multi page application with `steroids create` and see that structure. That installs Angular by default. The single page application creation doesn't install a specific framework like that. I didn't mention that before.